# Authentication in Angular2

Tags: angular

Firstly, I am a student and beginner. In my quest to become a better developer, I have started to develop small apps to scan and open a webpage. Now, I am moving on to next step.

I am trying to create a user login page, so for that I am trying to understand what is needed and how to accomplish creating a sign-up/login for an Angular2 framework. In our university we are using mySQL database written in PHP.

I have these questions:

- How do I start?
- Can you guys suggest me something basic to learn at first?
- What are my potential road-blocks?
- Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, before you going to work with database try to create login/singup page withing dummy data.(without database values).If you success then you can start with database.Then you can get many ideas about your work

[Here](http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/) is some example with dummy data.Try to do this.